# Cake PHP3 rest API get public URL for images

Tags: php, api, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I'm creating rest API in cake PHP3 and I need to add some API versioning to endpoints.
Ex: domein - `www.test.com`
versioning - `/test/api/v1/` 
So users endpoint like to be `www.test.com/test/api/v1/users`

I've changed the `routes.php` file as below.

```
Router::scope('/test/api/v1/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
```

Above change is work fine in endpoints but when I try to get public image URL's that images in `webroot/img` directory as below it says `Controller class Img is missing`

`http://test.com/test/api/v1/img/cake.png`

1. Am I used correct cake PHP3 way to change the endpoint URL ?
2. If so how could I get the public URL as above for `webroot/img` images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CakePHP is good practice to create different versions of the REST API as separate plugins, for example plugin ApiV10.

Inside plugin routes.php add like this:

```
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
Router::extensions(['json']);
Router::plugin(
    'ApiV10',
    ['path' => '/api/v1'],
    function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->connect(
            '/autosuggestions/locations',
            ['controller' => 'Autosuggestions', 'action' => 'locations','_ext' => 'json']
            );
        $routes->connect('/users', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
        $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
    }
);
```

In your controllers method set data array with full path to webroot/img/yourimages.jpg. Full path also can be modified in your **Entity**

[**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators)